# Implemented Foreign Key relationship between Employees and Departments Tables. I am getting DepartmentName value Null. I am using .NET-6 Razor Page

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

**Tables** 

*I created table like this with Foreign key relationship.*

```
create table Departments
(
    Id int primary key identity,
    Name varchar(100)
)
```

```
create table Employees
(
    Id int primary key identity,
    Name nvarchar(max),
    Salary decimal,
    DepartmentId int foreign key references Departments(Id)
)
```

**Model** 

*I have created Employees and Departments Models with the relationship*

```
public class Employees
{
        public int Id { get; set; }     
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }   

        public virtual Departments Department { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Departments
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Employees> Employees { get; set; }    
}
```

**ViewModel** 

*This is View Model to show the Employee and Department data. Here I also want to show DepartmentName*

```
public class EmployeesVM
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public string DepartmentName { get;set; }
}
```

**Auto Mapper Class**

```
namespace EmployeeDetails.Helpers
{
    public class AutoMapperHelper:Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperHelper()
        {
            CreateMap<Employees, EmployeesVM>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DepartmentName, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src.Department.Name); });
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace EmployeeDetails.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        private readonly ApplicationContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger,ApplicationContext context,IMapper mapper)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public List<EmployeesVM> EmployeesVM { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
           var result = _context.Employees.ToList();
            EmployeesVM = _mapper.Map<List<EmployeesVM>>(result);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see in the image 'DepartmentName' getting null:
[image: You can see in the image 'DepartmentName' getting null]

Comment: You need to use `_context.Employees.Include(e => e.Department).ToList()` to also get the departments loaded

Comment: Personally, I use singular names for tables, but I know a lot of people don't. I think of the table as a template where others think of it as a collection. That's fine. What's not fine is using plural names for your entities. Those entities should absolutely be named `Department` and `Employee`.

Comment: sir, I created it without migration in my company all projects are following same convention means Model Name should be same as Table Name

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 different approaches to [loading related entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) via navigation properties in the model. It seems that [lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy) is not enabled in your case (and personally I'm not a big fan of it), so you need to either [explicitly load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit) them or use [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager):

```cs
var result = _context.Employees
    .Include(e => e.Department)
    .ToList();
EmployeesVM = _mapper.Map<List<EmployeesVM>>(result);
```

**UPD**

Also possibly you would like to use Automapper's has [queryable extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) to prevent overfetching an handle the relations via the `ProjectTo<>` method which will tell AutoMapper’s mapping engine to emit a select clause to the IQueryable that will inform entity framework that it only needs to query some of the fields.

Note that `ProjectTo` has quite a lot of limitations in terms of supported mappings ([see this part of the docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options)).

Comment: Here Employees Table have only one reference like Departments. If we have more than one table then, how it will write

Comment: @MDSAQUIBRAZA then you will need multiple includes. Also please see the update.